# mvn depedency plugin and Hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop

I've got a jar that contains both some map reduce code and a few command line tools.

To distribute my dependencies I'm packaging all my dependences in a lib directoy within my jar using the maven dependency plugin:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-classpath</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      configure the plugin here 
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I was hoping to have my jar use the lib directory when i run various classes from the command line java -cp myJar.jar org.mycompany.MyClass

However, this doesn't see to work despite my best efforts to manipulate the MANIFEST.MF

```
<configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                      <mainClass>com.mycompany.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
```

Is there a way to do this without using the maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: Why " without using the maven-assembly-plugin " ?

Comment: I already know how to use the assembly plugin to do this. I'm just curious to know if there is an alternate that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about using these dependencies in map/reduce jobs. If so take a look at [this article](http://www.datasalt.com/2011/05/handling-dependencies-and-configuration-in-java-hadoop-projects-efficiently/) from Pere Ferrera Bertran which explains how to use hadoop's distributed cache (and two other ways) to do that